# How can I find response cookie names in Postman tests?

Tags: testing, cookies, postman

Is there a way to retrieve the response cookie names in a Postman test?  I can get values with `postman.getResponseCookie("<COOKIENAME>").value`.  However, based on differing scenarios, the cookiename changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get and store the value of a cookie using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259402/get-and-store-the-value-of-a-cookie-using-postman)

Answer (score 3):

Got it!  I evaluated `responseCookies` to determine the cookie name.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: That I know, and its already stated in the question text. How do you get the cookies names?

Comment: console.log(responseCookies);

Answer (score 3):

You can check for a specific cookie in a test like this:

```
pm.test("Response contains a JSESSIONID cookie", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.cookies.has('JSESSIONID')).to.be.true;
});
```

This works for me in Postman v7.3.6 without the Postman interceptor turned on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **response** cookie, and not for **current** cookie, better check it from response header (set-cookie).

### Example

```js
pm.test('Response has correct cookie', function () {
    // Get response cookies from header.
    // Response can have multiple set-cookie headers.
    // Variable i is an Header object which has property key and value.
    const cookies = pm.response.headers.filter((i) => i.key === 'set-cookie');
    // Make sure that at least have 1 set-cookie header.
    pm.expect(cookies).to.not.have.lengthOf(0);
    // Get cookie value and extract the name: (position 0 before =).
    const cookieValues = cookies.map((i) => i.value.split('=')[0]);
    // Make sure the length is the same.
    pm.expect(cookieValues.length).to.equal(cookies.length);
    // Make sure to have specific cookie name.
    pm.expect(cookieValues).to.includes('somecookiename');
    pm.expect(cookieValues).to.includes('JSESSIONID');
  });
```

**References:**
Postman [Response](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-with-response-data), [Header](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Header.html) and [HeaderList](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/HeaderList.html) documentation.