# Get and store the value of a cookie using Postman

Tags: cookies, postman

I need to get the value of a cookie, that is only created when I send a request in postman.

I have tried everything but I don't know how to achieve this. I also need to store that value to use in further requests for my project.

`cookie name: JSESSIONID
value:09840****************00C44`

Comment: Please ask a clear question. I don't get anything from that long sentence missing all punctuation

Comment: The question is actually vague and lacking details but I can provide an answer to this as it’s something i’ve answered before - I bit more searching would have made this question redundant.

Comment: Try this:-
var value = postman.getResponseCookie("key").value;

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could use the `pm.environment.set('my_cookie', pm.cookies.get('JSESSIONID'))` function in the `Tests` tab and store it as an `environment` variable.

This can then be used in the next Request Body (If chaining them together) or in any Request Body or Request Header by referencing the value using the `{{my_cookie}}` syntax.

A very similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190911/extract-cookie-value-from-request-postman-jmeter).

Comment: A precision: to be saved and re-used, the env variable must have been declared in a managed environment in Postman (the user should first create an environment if he's not using one, then declare an environment variable, and then he can set its value using the aforementioned command in Tests).

Plus, in recent versions of Postman I think the syntax has changed, it is now:
`postman.setEnvironmentVariable('my_cookie', pm.cookies.get('JSESSIONID'));`

Comment: It's the opposite way around, that would be the older syntax you have used. To overcome the need to create an environment beforehand,you could swap out `environment` and use either `collectionVariables` or `globals` in it's place. These wouldn't need to be created before the request is sent.

Comment: My bad, I was indeed using the older syntax without knowing. Thanks for the complementary info!

Comment: Can you explain what "next/any" is and where to find this option in postman?

Comment: By that, I think I meant (It was a while ago) `next` request in the Collection, if you're chaining the requests and running them sequentially or `any` request body if the value is set in an accessible variable scope.